NodeJS во время отладки не скрывает системные переменные?
Во время отладки кода (использую NodeJS) отладчик всёравно показывает системные переменные. Мне они не интересны. Как их убрать?
Использовал файл launch.json с настройками (указаны будут ниже), но получилось скрыть только "Call Stack". Перепробывал всевозможные комбинации для параметра "Skipfiles". Но ни один из них не скрыл именно системные переменные.

{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [ 
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch",
            "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
        }
    ],
    "debug.javascript.terminalOptions": {
        "skipFiles": [
          "<node_internals>/**"
        ]
    }
}

